# trying to implement Selection Sort in Python, result is incorrect

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

I am trying to implement Selection Sort in Python myself while reading a book on algorithms. Below code results some of the items to be replaced correctly, however, some of them are not changing.

```
list = [23, 65, -9, 19, 90, 0, -1]


def sel_sort(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        sm_item = A[i]
        for j in range(1+i, len(A)):
            if A[j] < sm_item:
                A[i], A[j] = sm_item, A[i]
    return A

print(sel_sort(list))
```

the results is: [23, 65, 65, 65, 90, 90, 90]

Can't figure out why this result?

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like this

```
list = [23, 65, -9, 19, 90, 0, -1]


def sel_sort(A):
 for i in range(len(A)):
    sm_item = A[i]
    for j in range(1+i, len(A)):
        if A[j] < sm_item:
            sm_item=A[j]
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
 return A

print(sel_sort(list))
```